# Not able to open panel or popup programatically in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, popup, panel

I'm building my first JQM site so I think I'm missing some simple little thing that's causing me a bunch of problems.

I have setup the page, header, content and footer and a panel for the menu. Then I have I have a js file with the following:

```js
$(document).on('pageinit', function (event) {

alert('this works every time you navigate to another page');
$("#menu-panel").panel("open");//this works the first time only
$("#new-lump-sum").popup("open");//this never works

});
```

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this behaviour instead of both the panel and the popup opening every time you navigate to another page?

I also can't open them programmatically from the browser console (using chrome)

This is my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Cashflow - IFA Portal</title>

    <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

    <link href="/Styles/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Styles/System.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/System.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="computer android">
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div data-role="page" class="page ui-responsive-panel"><!-- Start Page -->
               <div data-role="panel" id="menu-panel" data-position="left" data-display="reveal" data-theme="a" data-dismissible="false" class="">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search Items..." data-theme="a" data-filter-theme="a">
            <li><a href="/"><img src="/Images/Icons/home.png" alt="" class="ui-li-icon"/>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Tools"><img src="/Images/Icons/icon.png" alt="" class="ui-li-icon"/>Tools</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Tools/Cashflow"><img src="/Images/Icons/icon.png" alt="" class="ui-li-icon"/>Cashflow</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Client"><img src="/Images/Icons/icon.png" alt="" class="ui-li-icon"/>Clients</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Proposal"><img src="/Images/Icons/icon.png" alt="" class="ui-li-icon"/>Proposals</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Fund"><img src="/Images/Icons/icon.png" alt="" class="ui-li-icon"/>Funds</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
                <div id="header" data-role="header" data-theme="d">
        <div id="top-border"></div>
        <div class="floatleft">
            <a href="#menu-panel" title="Menu" id="menu-button" data-role="button" data-icon="grid" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="/Images/AllanGray-Logo.png" />
        </div>

        <div class="floatleft header-toolbar" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <a href="#right-panel" data-role="button" data-icon="star" title="Favourites">Favourites</a>
            <a href="#right-panel" data-role="button" title="Notes"><img src="/Images/Icons/179-notepad.png" class="ui-li-icon small-icon" />Notes</a>
            <a href="#display-options" data-role="button" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-icon="gear" title="Display Options">Display Settings</a>
        </div>


        <div id="logout">
            <section id="login">
                        <a href="/Account/Login" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-style="b">Log In</a>

            </section>   
        </div>

        <div id="display-options" data-role="popup" class="ui-content">
            <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
            <form>
                <fieldset id="theme-options" data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true" data-type="horizontal">
                    <legend>Theme</legend>
                        <input type="radio" name="theme" id="theme-1" value="android" checked="checked" />
                        <label for="theme-1" class="theme-option">Android</label>

                        <input type="radio" name="theme" id="theme-2" value="apple"  />
                        <label for="theme-2" class="theme-option">Apple</label>

                        <input type="radio" name="theme" id="theme-3" value="windows"  />
                        <label for="theme-3" class="theme-option">Windows</label>
                </fieldset>
                <br />
                <fieldset id="size-options" data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true" data-type="horizontal">
                    <legend>Screen Size</legend>
                        <input type="radio" name="size" id="size-1" value="computer" checked="checked" />
                        <label for="size-1" class="size-option">Computer</label>

                        <input type="radio" name="size" id="size-2" value="tablet"  />
                        <label for="size-2" class="size-option">Tablet</label>

                        <input type="radio" name="size" id="size-3" value="phone"  />
                        <label for="size-3" class="size-option">Phone</label>
                </fieldset>
           </form>
        </div>
    </div>

            <div id="content" data-role="content">






<h2>Cashflow Calculator</h2>

<div class="ui-grid-a">

    <div class="ui-block-a" style="padding-right:5px;">
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="c">
            <h3>Investment Assumptions</h3>

            <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="narrow">
                <label for="time">Time horizon (years)</label>
                <input type="range" name="time" id="time" value="20" min="0" max="100" data-highlight="true" style="width"/>

                <label for="nominal">Nominal return after unit trust fees (%)</label>
                <input type="text" name="nominal" id="nominal" value="" />

                <label for="inflation">Inflation rate p.a. (%)</label>
                <input type="text" name="inflation" id="inflation" value="" />

                <label for="administration-fees">Net platform administration fees (%)</label>
                <input type="text" name="administration-fees" id="administration-fees" value="" />

                <label for="advisor-fees">Financial advisor fees (%)</label>
                <input type="text" name="advisor-fees" id="advisor-fees" value="" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <a href="#new-lump-sum" data-role="button" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-icon="plus" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">Add Contributions or Withdrawals</a>

        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="c">
            <h3>Contributions & Withdrawals </h3>



            <ul id="lump-sums" data-role="listview" data-split-icon="delete" data-split-theme="d">
                <li>
                    <a>
                        <h3>Contribution: R20 000</h3>
                        <p class="topic"><strong>Recurres: 6 times</strong></p>
                        <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>Start Date: 01/08/2013</strong></p>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#demo-mail">
                        <h3>Contribution: R5000</h3>
                        <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>Start Date: 01/06/2013</strong></p>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#demo-mail">
                        <h3>Withdrawal: -R25 000</h3>
                        <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>Start Date: 01/06/2013</strong></p>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>



        <div data-role="popup" id="new-lump-sum" class="ui-content">
            <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
            <form>
                <fieldset id="lump-sum-type" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                    <legend>Add New</legend>
                        <input type="radio" name="lump-sum-type" id="contribution" value="contribution" checked="checked" />
                        <label for="contribution" class="">Contribution</label>

                        <input type="radio" name="lump-sum-type" id="withdrawal" value="withdrawal"  />
                        <label for="withdrawal" class="">Withdrawal</label>
                </fieldset>

                <label for="lump-sum-amount">Amount (R)</label>
                <input type="text" name="lump-sum-amount" id="lump-sum-amount" value="" />

                <label for="lump-sum-date">Date</label>
                <input type="text" name="lump-sum-date" id="lump-sum-date" value="" />

                <a data-role="button" data-theme="b" onclick="addLumpSum()">Add</a>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="ui-block-b" style="padding-left:5px;">
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="c">
            <h3>Future Value Graph</h3>


            <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;">fgjfjfgjh</div>

            <script type="text/javascript">


            </script>


        </div>

    </div>
</div>


            </div>

            <div id="footer" data-role="footer">
    <div id="bottom-border"></div>
    <p>Copyright © 2013 Allan Gray. All Rights Reserved.</p>
</div>
                <div data-role="panel" id="right-panel" data-position="right" data-display="overlay" data-theme="b">
        <a href="#page" data-rel="close" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="delete"></a>
        <h3>Favourites</h3>
        <div id="search-box">
            <input type="search" name="search-mini" id="search-mini" value="" data-mini="true" placeholder="Search..." />
        </div>
    </div>





            <script>

            </script>

        </div><!-- End Page -->
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Popups and dialogs are tricky when it comes to opening them right after a page event occurs. To fix this issue, you need to use `setTimeout` to open a dialog or a popup.

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function() {
 setTimeout(function () {
  $('#new-lump-sum').popup('open');
 }, 100); // delay above zero
});
```

Comment: I tried that and it works, but only the first time I load the page, then when I navigate away from the page with the popup and back it does not open again.

Comment: @MikhailJanowski because you're using `pageinit` which fires once only. If you want it to open each time the page opens, use `pageshow` instead.

Comment: could it have something to do with the ID being duplicated when the second page is loaded? I tried using classes but that caused a js error.

Comment: class should work with no problems whatsoever. Duplicate ID could cause some problems. `$(document).on('pageshow', '[data-role=page]#pageID', function()`

Comment: @MikhailJanowski you should have panel in each page.

Comment: using a class like this does nothing `$(".new-lump-sum").popup("open");` and I have added the class to the popup div

Comment: I do have a panel on each page

Comment: @MikhailJanowski Try `$("[data-role=panel].new-lump-sum").popup("open");` **EDIT:** I just tested it, it only works with `ID`, it's weird that classes are being neglected.

Comment: @Omar, won't using pageinit result in it opening when ever a page is initialised?

Comment: @phil as long as the page isn't fully visible, it will open and close immediately. That's why you need to setTimeout to ensure that the page is shown. Especially in previous JQM versions.

Comment: @Omar, I just meant pageinit will be called on every page. If he just wants to open the panel on 1 specific page, he'll need to use something else.